# How to forbid npm to upgrade itself when running npm run start?

Tags: docker, npm

In Dockerfile we have command: `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]`. But when running it in CI where actual image is built, npm tries to update itself (since we are using not the latest npm version). And fails with insufficient permission error.

Base image defined like: `FROM node:8.16` and this version includes npm 6.4.1.

I searched and couldn't find a way to tell npm to not try to update when running some script.

Comment: which docker image you are using or base image? in the context of docker, these two thing means a lot to help :)

Comment: I added info about image - Node 8.16, which includes 6.4.1 npm.

Comment: okay let me post the answer. you can downgrade the npm version as per your required version during you docker image build time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image comes with `npm version 6.4.1` and there is no logic in the base image that update NPM itself but it come with `6.4.1`. All you need to downgrade npm version in your Dockerfile.

In the below example the base image has `6.4.1` and the Dockerfile will downgrade the version to `npm@3.10.10`. Replace the version the one you required.

```
FROM node:8.16
COPY . /
RUN npm install -g npm@3.10.10
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Run the command in the container  and check the version of NPM using `npm -v` you should see `3.10.10`

`docker exec mynode bash -c "npm -v"`

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: @Adiii maybe `copy . /` should be capitalized?